# Accessing Client Behind Router

Tags: udp, client-server, portforwarding

I'm working on toy UDP client/server programs for an undergraduate research project I am doing. I've got my server up and running on a Raspberry Pi and configured port range forwarding on my home router to get messages passed to the server properly. What I'm having trouble with, though, is getting messages back to the client through their router.

Example: I have my server up and running and send a connect message to it from a client process. My server receives the message and sends back an ack, but it's never received by the client because the server sends the ack to the client's external IP and is subsequently dropped by the client router (because the router has no idea what to do with the message).

I feel like there has to be a well-defined solution to this problem, but I just don't know enough about networking to even know where to start looking.